# Regular expression to allow single whitespace between words

Tags: regex

I would like to know a regular expression to allow whitespace. My example is an item name(2 words). It can be made of uppercase, lowercase letters and one whitespace. I.e `word1 word2`. I tried with `[A-Za-z\sA-Za-z]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: `/\b[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+\b/` should work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
[A-Za-z]+(\s[A-Za-z]+)?
```

This allows one word, optionally followed by a single whitespace and another word, which requires the whitespace character to be only *between* two words, if present at all (ie the regex also allows for just a single word).

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the character classes. I've also used word breaks, so that this doesn't match `abc abc` in `123abc abc123`. The `+` means that at least 1 match is required (of the character, character class or group before it). Note that the `+` is also required on the character classes, since a single character class captures a single character.

```
\b[A-Za-z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+\b
```

If you only want to allow spaces:

```
\b[A-Za-z]+[ ]+[A-Za-z]+\b
```

The brackets around the space aren't required, but aid the regex visually.

Comment: This will allow arbitrary number of whitespace characters (space, tab, new line, etc.).

Comment: yep, and carriage return - if you don't want this, use the latter

Comment: Depending on the language, there are also Unicode whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r'[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$'
```

This allows one word, optionally followed by a single whitespace and another word, which requires the whitespace character to be only between two words